# .Net WikiText to HTML Parser

Tags: .net, open-source, parsing, wikitext

I know, I know, its sounds silly, but it seems that there are no opensource robust .NET libraries out there for parsing Wikitext to HTML.

Anybody know of a stable.robust .net Wikitext to HTML parser (i.e. codeplex projects that are still in beta mode do not count)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [ScrewTurnWiki](https://stw.codeplex.com/). [Core/Formatter.cs](https://stw.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Core/Formatter.cs) has the HTML renderer, AFAICT.

Comment: Cheers, I forgot all about just ripping apart another c# wiki

Comment: Link dead, try this (for now...) : https://stw.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another option, the one used on codeplex has been made available as a .NET library:
http://wikiplex.codeplex.com/