# Convert or parse wiki in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, wiki

Looking for a c# class or similar that can parse or convert wiki-formated text to html or similar.

Specs are here:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Markup_spec

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352623/net-wikitext-to-html-parser), you can rip apart the parse helper class from  [ScrewTurn Wiki](https://stw.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WikiNetParser.aspx) (Wiki .NET Parser).
Also, you can look an example of parsing on [this article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/wiki).